# Get first date smaller than given date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am storing several dates in a MySQL database.

- `1992-01-03`
- `1990-02-30`
- `1990-01-28`
- `1990-01-13`
- `1990-01-01`

(Note: The order of the dates is not the same as the order in my database)

If I referenced the date **`1990-01-29`** for any arbitrary reason, and I needed to get the first date that was smaller than **`1990-01-29`**, how could I create a query that would do that for me?

Comment: `1990-02-30` isn't a real date :-)

Comment: Double Leap Year!

Comment: My bad, the example 1990-02-30 just an example.  Thanks for editing it, it looks much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for all dates that are less than the one you want, sort the result and just grab one row.  Something like:

```
SELECT theDate
FROM yourTable
WHERE theDate < '1990-01-29'
ORDER BY theDate DESC
LIMIT 1
```